# How to read csv files from different paths folders, with configuration files attached for each dataset in Python?

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, list, read-data

I have worked in R until now. And I am trying to replicate my work in python. 
Thus, in R I have been able to read different datasets from different path folders into a list of list. On this list, I have applied a function that has standardised the data using configuration files that were stored into the same list where data was stored. But for now I am just trying to read the data and configuration files into a list of list in python and do not know how? Can someone please help with this?

This is what I have done in R and this is how I read the data.

```
import_list <- list(list(data_path = "../data/A.csv",
                         config_path = "/data/config/A/"),
                    list(data_path = "../data/B.csv",
                         config_path =  "/data/config/B/"),
                    list(data_path = "../data/C.csv", 
                         config_path = "../data/C/")))
```

I hope I can read the data I have in this format, but this time in python. Is there a simple way to read multiple csv data files from different paths folder into this format? This is how it should look like.

```
 import_list List of 3   
    :List of 2   
      data_path : chr "../data/A.csv  
      config_path: chr "config/A" 
    :List of 2   
      data_path: chr "../data/B.csv 
      config_path: chr "config/B"
```

Comment: Do you read both the CSV and config directory at the same time? Are you having trouble translating a filename into its configuration directory?

Comment: Yes, I do need to read both. But I do not want to read all configuration files into this list yet.  Since will apply a function that will read into configuration files and apply the standardisation on the csv data found in this list. Hopefully, it does make sense what I am describing here.

Comment: If you're reading your *data* similar to `datlist <- lapply(filelist, read.csv, ...)`, then you should be able to read the config dirs in a similar fashion, `cfglist <- lapply(file.path(dirname(filelist), gsub("\\.csv", basename(filelist))), read.config.dir)`. Then, if your standardization function is `myfunc <- function(dat, cfg) {...}`, then you can do `Map(myfunc, datlist, cfglist)`. Is that what you're needing?

Comment: @r2evans is this into python?, right? Because I am trying to replicate this in python

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read your intent. That's R code. (The [tag:r] code threw me off.)

Comment: Yes, i actually realised what you’ve written was in R. Hut want to replicate it in python.

Comment: @r2evans, are you aware of a library in python that can help me achieve what you've said? Actually, what you have explained, is exactly what I have done in R. But not sure where to start from when it comes to Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be enough:

```python
In [1]: from os import listdir

In [2]: from os.path import isfile, join

In [3]: from re import sub

In [4]: mypath = "test"

In [5]: onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)) ]

In [6]: configs = [ join(mypath, "config", sub("\.csv$", "", f)) for f in onlyfiles ]

In [7]: list(zip(onlyfiles, configs))
Out[7]: [('B.csv', 'test/config/B'), ('A.csv', 'test/config/A')]
```

Comment: thank you for this. Would you please help me understand the line 5th and 6th?

Comment: Those are [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), similar to a loop such as `onlyfiles = [];\nfor f in listdir(mypath):\n  if isfile(join(mypath,f)): onlyfiles.append(f)`.